# could not insert 'ip_tables': Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I used the Ubuntu 16.04 system and had problems configuring `iptables`. How to solve this problem?

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ip_tables': Operation not permitted
iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux SE. As this is your first question, you may not be familiar with our protocol. Please [read this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) first, and follow up when and if you've received a helpful answer. There's also a ["tour"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) you can take that will give you an overview, and may prove useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a problem configuring `iptables`, you have a problem loading the required module.

Are you running the command as `root`? The error `Operation not permitted` indicates that the module is not missing, you seem to lack the permission to load the module.

If you are running as `root`, it is also possible that additional restrictions prevent you from loading the module, such as AppArmor or SELinux.